# jQuery selectors with meta-characters

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, metacharacters

I'm having problem selecting an element with an id like this `<li ="0f:Bactidol_Recorder.mp4">.`

I tried using the function that escapes meta-characters with two backslashes below from this jquery [link](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How%5Fdo%5FI%5Fselect%5Fan%5Felement%5Fby%5Fan%5FID%5Fthat%5Fhas%5Fcharacters%5Fused%5Fin%5FCSS%5Fnotation.3F) but still can't select the element

Function:

```
function jq(myid) { 
   return '#' + myid.replace(/(:|\.)/g,'\\$1');
}
```

Example:

```
$(jq('0fb:Bactidol_Recorder.mp4')).empty()
```

Output:

```
$(#0fb\\:Bactidol_Recorder\\.mp4).empty();
```

Comment: I assume you mean `<li id="0f:Bactidol_Recorder.mp4">`?

Comment: It's worth noting that this isn't a valid HTML `id` attribute. They must start with a letter. (See the HTML TR: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-name )

Comment: It works for me:  http://jsbin.com/ajano3/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: [Your original code works fine](http://jsbin.com/ajano3/edit). (jQuery 1.4.2)

You could write

```
$('*[id="0fb:Bactidol_Recorder.mp4"]')
```

However, it'll be slower.

The fastest way to do this would be to write

```
$(document.getElementById("0fb:Bactidol_Recorder.mp4"))
```

Comment: Then you should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.